# Date tick label on plotyy

Tags: matlab

I'´m trying to plot two variables on a same graph using plotyy. The problem is, when I configure x-axis for date labels, it appears both date and another kind of number labels.
How can I set only date labels?

[image]

Below it follows the script:

```
    prp_dados = importdata ('c:\experimental\telemetricas_ANA\prp\29070100PARAUAPEBAS_1332013-2032013.txt');


cot_dados = importdata ('c:\experimental\telemetricas_ANA\cota\29070100PARAUAPEBAS_1332013-2032013.txt');

p_date_string = strcat (prp_dados.textdata(2:end,1),{' '}, prp_dados.textdata(2:end,2));
c_date_string = strcat (cot_dados.textdata(2:end,1),{' '}, cot_dados.textdata(2:end,2));
p_xdate = datenum (p_date_string, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM');

plotyy (p_xdate,cot_dados.data,p_xdate,prp_dados.data);

   set(gca,'XTick',p_xdate)
    datetick('x', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using gca to get only one handle, try using the syntax

```
[ax,h1, h2] = plotyy()
```

then you can set the properties for each plot individually.

Comment: I did as you recommended, but changing x-axis to date format (dd/mm/yyyy) is being quite hard.